# Having trouble getting aggregations working.

Tags: redis, redisearch

I'm in the midst of exploring RediSearch and I thought I'd give the aggregations feature a shot and have hit a roadblock.

I can't seem to get a good result.

For testing purposes I created a basic index/schema like so:

```
FT.CREATE test SCHEMA field TEXT

FT.ADD test 1A 1 FIELDS field hello
FT.ADD test 2A 1 FIELDS field hello
FT.ADD test 3A 1 FIELDS field hello
FT.ADD test 4A 1 FIELDS field world
```

Next, I issued the following query:

```
FT.AGGREGATE test "*" GROUPBY 1 @field REDUCE COUNT 0 AS agg
```

My expectation was that I get a result indicating `hello` occurs three times and `world` occurs once... but instead I get the following result:

```
1) (integer) 1
2) 1) "field"
   2) (nil)
   3) "agg"
   4) "4"
```

I thought it was pretty straight forward... but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Also, the following is the output from the `MODULE LIST` command:

```
1) 1) "name"
   2) "ft"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10300
2) 1) "name"
   2) "ReJSON"
   3) "ver"
   4) (integer) 10001
```

Any help would be super.

Thanks!

Comment: Please try after defining the field as `SORTABLE` during schema creation.

Comment: Also, consider upgrading to RediSearch v1.4.1 that was released earlier today

Comment: @ItamarHaber I updated to the latest version of Redis and RediSearch AND made the property I was aggregating on `SORTABLE`. Making the property `SORTABLE` seems to have done the trick. Did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: Another way to go about this, w/o reverting to the use of sortable fields, is to tune the (currently global) timeout - that's basically the classic space-time trade-off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that I should have read the documentation better.

From the section in the [aggregations documentation](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Aggregations/) where they describe the `FT.AGGREGATE` command parameters they mention `LOAD {nargs} {property}`, where they say:

> Load document fields from the document HASH objects. This should be
>   avoided as a general rule of thumb. Fields needed for aggregations
>   should be stored as **SORTABLE**, where they are available to the
>   aggregation pipeline with very low latency. **LOAD** hurts the performance
>   of aggregate queries considerably since every processed record needs
>   to execute the equivalent of HMGET against a redis key, which when
>   executed over millions of keys, amounts to very high processing times.

From the query example in the original question I had:

`FT.AGGREGATE test "*" GROUPBY 1 @field REDUCE COUNT 0 AS agg`

Since the schema definition didn't have `field` defined as `SORTABLE` I would have to `LOAD` "field" in order to perform an aggregation on it.

`FT.AGGREGATE test "*" LOAD 1 @field GROUPBY 1 @field REDUCE COUNT 0 AS agg`

However, since according to the documentation `LOAD` hurts performance I should have instead defined the field I want to aggregate as `SORTABLE`.

`FT.CREATE test SCHEMA field TEXT SORTABLE`

With the schema properly defined my original query works.